# c# System.Xml.XmlReader ReadInnerXml()

Tags: c#, java, xml

what's the equivalent method of XMLStreamReader in java.
I want to use it in the following case.
 case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT.

Comment: i think i have misunderstood your question as you posted with a c# tag; are you asking the java equivalent of an XmlReader function? or vice versa?  either way would you mind editing your question to clarify exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't describe the question clearly. I am converting a c# project to java. So I replace System.Xml.XmlReader with  XMLStreamReader in java. But I don't know the equivalent method  ReadInnerXml().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you are looking for is `getElementText()`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getElementText()

this was given as returning all XML underneath the current element as opposed to a feature request for innerText() in a site i came across, however, i can't seem to track down the link.